# How to set p-multiSelect values from sessionStorage in Angular?

Tags: angular, multi-select, session-storage

I could save the selections of a p-multiSelect into sessionStorage. But can not set them as in sessionStorage after refreshing of my Browser.

component.html:

```
<th class="status-filter-header">
    <p-multiSelect
      name="app.environment"
      [options]="environments"
      placeholder="alle..."
      [showClear]="true"
      [(ngModel)]="selectedEnvironments"
      (onChange)="onFilter($event, 'app.environment', 'in', 'envValues', selectedEnvironments)"
      styleClass="p-column-filter"
    >
    </p-multiSelect>
  </th>
```

the onFilter-Method in component.ts:

```
public onFilter(event: any, field: string, selector: string, sessionName: string, sessionValue: any): void {
this.updateFilterCounter(event);
this.table.filter(event.target ? event.target.value : event.value, field, selector);

if (sessionName === 'envValues') {
  sessionStorage.setItem(sessionName, JSON.stringify(sessionValue));
} else {
  sessionStorage.setItem(sessionName, sessionValue);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got the solution:

Just say in `ngOnInit()` Method `this.selectedEnvironments = JSON.parse(sessionStroage.getItem('envValues');`